# what is the correct notation to insert a specific kind of an edge to a graph

Tags: graph-theory, notation

what is the correct notation to insert a specific kind of edge to a graph? is it okay to use a 3-tuple

$\mathit{graph} \gets (a, b, \mathit{direct})$

$\mathit{graph} \gets (a, b, \mathit{transitive})$

Comment: Forgive me if this is known to most graph theorists, but what is a "transitive" edge? It's hard to search for because of concepts like edge-transitive graphs.

Comment: direct edge from a to b and direct edge from b to c results in transitive edge from a to c

Comment: Then how do you expect to insert “transitive edges”? In general, there will be many ways of realizing the same transitive edge through direct edges. Your notation does not specify which of those is meant. (Inserting transitive edges does not seem to make sense.)